# How to extract value per voxel in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-spm

I am doing SPM on brain images and I want to extract the value of T-stat for each voxel (in mm coordinate rather than voxel coordinate). Is there any function do that in Matlab?

The image is the SPM result rather than raw image.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please indicate in your question what you've tried so far? Even if it's only a few websearches, or failed attempts, it is helpful to know what direction you're exploring.

Comment: Hi Saaru we have looked at FSLmeants to do this but it did not seem to interpolate the result